# Cannot add JLabel or JButton to a JFrame. The frame won't show it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to add `JLabel` to a `JFrame` but it doesn't show. I've tried adding `JButton` also but it does't seem to work. I've tried so many things over the past few days.

Anything wrong with my code?

```
public class F2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    int j = 2;
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F2 f = new F2();

    }

    public F2() {
        j++;
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1380, 728);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Timer t = new Timer(20, this);
        t.restart();
        label.setText("Test");

        add(label);
frame.pack();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            people.add(new Person(0));
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Places p1 = new Places(g);
        for (Person p : people) {
            p.paint(g); //recall that each Person object has a paint method. We're passing g as the argument
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have added the label to your panel F2 and then add your panel to the frame.  Now your empty panel replaces the label.

Comment: Put it as a reply so he can accept it

Comment: I've also tried it but it doesn't seen to work. I've replaced frame.add(label) with add(label); But there is no changes . Or is my command wrong?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will help you learn how Swing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying Alex Rudenko answer:

You should have added the label to your panel and then add your panel to the frame. Now your empty panel replaces the label.

```
this.add(label)
frame.add(this)
```

Maybe make it also visible and play with the coordinates and the size... or just copy a premade code from the internet... the way you are using the jpanel in the main class is maybe confusing you.

Comment: I've also tried it but it doesn't seen to work. I've replaced frame.add(label) with add(label); But there is no changes

Comment: Actually using the Jpanel in the main class is indeed confusing. But I'm just learning it for my 1st year project so I'm not so sure if I'm doing it right. I've am now trying to do it in seperate class but still having problem. Btw I have tried this code and still nothing. Is it because of my ActionListener kept on repainting?

Comment: The actionlistener seems ok

Comment: Hi. I just found out that if I change super.paintcomponent(g) to super.paint(g) it actually prints the label, but i cannot reposition the label it stays on the top.

Comment: Check the type of layout and how to position, you are advancing :)